# compositionTarget.rendering: changing variable

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently using CompositionTarget.Rendering for my graphics for my projectile simulation but I don't know how to get my acceleration to change. Is it possible to like it to a variable and be databinded to it so as it changes so does the acceleration?

Thanks for any help.

My code so far:

```
    private Point position; // in pixels
    private Vector Velocity; // in pixels per second
    private Vector acceleration; // in pixels per square second

    Velocity = new Vector(HVelTemp, VVelTemp); // y direction is downwards
    acceleration = new Vector(0, -1 * newEnvironment.gravity * PixelPerMeter); // y direction is downwards
    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        position = new Point(5, (HighestPoint * PixelPerMeter)); // fix later pls
        int removedtime = 0;
        time = DateTime.Now;
        RenderingEvent = (s, g) => OnRendering(s, g, removedtime, time);
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += RenderingEvent;
    }

    private void OnRendering(object sender, EventArgs g, int removedtime, DateTime t)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-removedtime);
        var dt = (now - t).TotalSeconds;
        time = now;
        position += Velocity * dt;
        Velocity += acceleration * dt;
        projectileGeometry.Center = position;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may declare `Acceleration` as dependency property. Thus it will be bindable. The following declaration assumes that your code is in class MainWindow.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AccelerationProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Acceleration", typeof(Vector), typeof(MainWindow));

public Vector Acceleration
{
    get { return (Vector)GetValue(AccelerationProperty); }
    set { SetValue(AccelerationProperty, value); }
}

...
Velocity += Acceleration * dt;
```

Comment: could you have acceleration as a vector instead of a double?

Comment: No problem thanks for the help! so instead of changing velocity I change the AccelerationProperty? Sorry, I dont really know how to make this work :/

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you are trying to do. However, you've asked for a changeable acceleration. So if in the middle of your simulation you'd change the acceleration from (0, -g) to (0, +g), your projektile would suddenly be accelerated upwards instead of downwards.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Basically, I am trying to factor in air resistance which keeps changing which is why I need to change the acceleration but I am not sure how to use the dependency variable.

Comment: Air resistance does not mean decreased gravity. Instead of changing the acceleration, you would have to subtract a value from the velocity that dependends in a certain way from the absolute velocity value. The most simple resistance calculation would subtract a value that is proportional to the speed.

Comment: Well, i worked out air resistance using the drag resistance equation which gave me air resistance as a force then i used f=ma to find my to find my deceleration due to air resistance. Since air resistance is always opposite to travel, can't i just subtract the acceleration to the acceleration of the particle at a time instance?

Comment: F=ma means the force that is exerted by an acceleration. Linear drag means a force like F=-bv (see Stokes drag).

Comment: Oh daaaaamn, thanks for that :P you are better than my physics teacher haha

Comment: So... how do I do this in a programming sense? do i just use the dependencyproperty like you said for acceleration?

Comment: I guess you don't need a dependency property, as it seems you don't want to change any of the kinematics parameters during the simulation. Instead, there would be other, more complicated equations that determine the current velocity and position of the projectile. You may calculate the kinematics with either Stokes drag or Newton drag (maybe more appropriate for air resistance). But these are out of the scope of this question.

Comment: The thing i dont understand is since the drag velocity is dependent on the relative motion of the projectile and the fluid wont that mean that the resistance will keep changing and maybe i would need the dependency property?

Comment: You would need a dependency property if you wanted to modify some parameter externally, e.g. change the strength of the gravitation, or the density of the air, while the simulation is running.